# Jquery - append function takes too much time

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to insert large data into DOM. I retrieve the data from DB using jquery ajax method. The data I receive is a list of ul and li and it has a list of around 6k records. The received data, I need to insert into the treeview structure. Below is the code where I'm using ajax method and trying to insert the received data using append function. The append function takes lot of time while inserting. Is there a way to improve the performance?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "TreeView.aspx/GetTreeOnDemand",
    data: '{labelTitle: "' + $(load)[0].title + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if(result.d) {
            $(that).siblings().remove();
            $(that).closest("li").append(result.d);
            $(that).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        } else {
            $(that).parent().removeClass('parent active');
            $(image).insertBefore(that)
        }
    }                                             
});
```

So far I have tried pushing the received data into array and then appending the array, but couldn't see any improvement. Please help

Comment: What's a lot of time? Also, are you sure it's the `append` function? This test: https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/qdzqraz8/ of appending 6k `ul` `li`s doesn't appear to take that long to me but it depends on the computer I guess.

Comment: @Damo-s, It's taking almost 13-15 seconds to load the 6k data.Each of the li element looks like below. Does addition of attributes hinders the performance in anyway?                                                                       <li id='1234'><img style='VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle' src='1/ig_treeL.gif' /><label title='ABC/XYZ' ondblclick='javascript:HandleClick(this)'><span style='VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle'>Name</span></label></li>

Comment: In my example it does appear to: https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/qdzqraz8/2/ This second jsfiddle demo takes me about 4 seconds to load compared to the earlier one which was about two seconds. If you could cut the time it takes to append in half that would be a big improvement. Are you able to alter the data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option of simplifying your database structure to the bare minimum (maybe just a json formatted string of id, title, and Name) it would probably help greatly, and then you could use native javascript methods like '[createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)`and`[createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)` to create and append the list items (first to a document fragment and then the whole thing at once to the target parent element.)

That said I created a simplified version of the data you're appending, taking out inline styles, removing unneeded elements and styling everything with CSS and attaching the click handler in the js rather than inline:

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/1e9qvycj/)**

With that many records to append it naturally won't be instant, but there are things you could try: 1. first appending just, say, 100 or so records so we can display something instantly at first, and then append the rest after. 2. adding a 'loading' animation of some sort, and this even could offer an opportunity for some creativity. 3. don't load all records - include pagination or an ajax 'load more' button.

```
var that = '.test1';
var jsonData = {
    'd': buildVeryLongData()
};

function buildVeryLongData() {
    var str = '<ul class="tree">';

    for (var i = 0; i < 6000; i++) {
        str += '<li id="' + i +'"><label title="ABC/XYZ">Name</label></li>';
    }

    str += '</ul>'
    return str;
}

function HandleClick(el) {
    // Handle Click
    console.log(el);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data : { json: JSON.stringify( jsonData ) },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if(result.d)
        {
         $(that).siblings().remove();
         $(that).closest("li").append(result.d);
         $(that).parent().children('ul').slideToggle('fast');

         // attach handler here
         $('.tree label').on('dblclick', function () {
             HandleClick(this);
         });
        }
        else
        {
         $(that).parent().removeClass('parent active');
         //$(image).insertBefore(that)
        }
    }                                             
});
```

CSS:

```
// example
.tree li:before {
  content: url('../1/ig_treeL.gif');
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

// example
.tree label {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="test1"></li>
</ul>
```